Setting up new connection using Oauth2.0
enter image description hereWhile setting up the oauth2.0 connection in event bridge with grant type as ClientCredemtials, how to declare the scope?
I tried using http parameters- query string type (key: scope and value: scopes separated by space.
Not working.
How to declare the scope?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Added the screenshot as there is no code.
